# Flying Saucer Batik and running footers dont work together?

Tags: java, css, pdf, flying-saucer, batik

Ive got a challenge for you guys. Im trying to create an xhtml doc with footer with an SVG image in it and then render it as pdf.
I use a combination of Flying Saucer and Batik to do this. Now I learned that Flying Saucer supports running footers, e.g.

```
@page {
  @top { content: element(footer); }
}
footer { position: running(footer); }
```

That works fine for me, but a problem arises when I add an SVG image with Batik:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .footer { position: running(footer); } 
    @page { @bottom-center { content: element(footer) } } 
    .header__logo {display: block; right: 0; top: 0; width: 150px; height: 54px; } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="footer">
        <img class='header__logo' src='someSRC.svg' />
        footer
    </div>
    <div class="content"> stuff </div>
</body>
```

It looks like Batik renders the image before it is moved to the bottom of the page. Also it does not display the 'footer' word anywhere.
Anyone know how to fix this? Maybe force Batik to render later or something?
Ive tried setting the position of the inner image to relative and more, but it really seems to mess up the process.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem myself. Though I still could not solve the entire issue, I managed at least to get the SVG displayed: you absolutely need to add css styles for height and width on your `<img>` element (via class or style attribute). Without both these attributes, no SVG gets drawn at all (at least not when you are using the sample codes flying around in the web).

Having achieved the rendering itself, I realised that the SVG will be positioned relative to the page content top-left corner (means, not within the header or footer area, where you'd expect it). Furthermore, it only gets drawn on the first page (whereas PNG images do not have either of these issues).

If anyone has a working solution for this, please post it here. For me this is unfortunately a show-stopper for using flying saucer at all in a professional context.

**Edit:**

Digging in the source code of flying saucer and iText I found a "work around" that might actually solve the issue for me: if you convert your SVGs into PDFs, then you can include the logo as PDF directly instead of an SVG. Seems like iText. So what works fine even in headers and footers is a usage in such a way:

```
<img style="width: 30mm; height:8mm;" src="/img/my-funky-logo.pdf"/>
```